# garamond (main) and mathpple (greek symbols)

Tags: fonts, math-mode, greek

i'm using GARAMOND font. But i would like some greek symbols to take from MATHPPLE. I think it's enough to write a command like "\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathalpha}{Letters}{5}". But i coldn't find the correct command. maybe there are similar answers but i couldn't use them.
Thanks in advance.